# Graphing Cartesian product of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, graphing-functions, relations

Question:

> Let $D$ be the following subset of $\mathbb{R}$ :
>
> $D = \left[1,3\right]\cup \left\{4\right\} $
>
> Graph $D \times D$.

I am not sure how to graph the Cartesian product of these kinds of sets. Could anyone show me how to graph this particular one and how to graph Cartesian product of sets in general?

Thanks.

Comment: Just draw all the points (x,y) so that x and are either between 1 and 3, or equal to 4.  What do you think that would look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take the set $D$ and make all possible pairs out of that set (since you are asked $D$ $\times$ $D$). In general, if $B$ is another set, and you want $D$ $\times$ $B$, then $D$ $\times$ $B$ = { (x,y) such that x $\epsilon$ $D$ and y $\epsilon$ $B$ } where if you replace $B$ by $D$, you get what you asked. Note that $D$ $\times$ $B$ and $B$ $\times$ $D$ aren't equal if $B$ is not he same as $D$. The first set (conventionally) comes on x-axis and the second on y-axis and so on if there are more than two sets.

Alternatively, for ease of understanding, fix one element of $D$ on x-axis and make pair of it with elements of $D$ on y-axis. This will give you points on top of the fixed point and then repeat it with another fixed element until you exhaust $D$ on x-axis. For example, fix point {2} from $D$ on x-axis and make pairs (2,y) where y varies in $D$ on y-axis. This will give you {2} $\times$ $D$. Now change the fixed point to another point in $D$ on x-axis and repeat the process until every element of $D$ is used as a fixed point, which wil give $D$ $\times$ $D$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the theorems (A cup B) x C = AxC cup BxC
and A x (B cup C) = AxB cup AxC.  Thus
DxD = [1,3]x[1,3] cup [1,3]x{4} cup {4}x[1,3] cup {4}x{4}.